Count views without get_post_meta
I was able to get the views through the function using get_post_meta and it works fine.
//Getter
function get_the_views($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0";
    }
    return $count.' ';
}

//Setter
function set_the_views($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}

However, I would like to do the same by creating a separate table in my wordpress database
First, I create my table:
Function create_post_view_table() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = 'myprefix_posts_views';
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name (
        `pvid` INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `ip` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `device` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `postid` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `create_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        PRIMARY KEY (`pvid`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";
    $wpdb->query($sql);
}
add_action('init', 'create_post_view_table');

Then, for each view of my posts, I wanted to insert infos into my table...
function increment_post_view_count() {
    global $post, $wpdb;
    if (isset($post->ID)) {
        $post_view_sql = $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO 'myprefix_posts_views' (postid, ip, device) VALUES (%d, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE create_at=VALUES(create_at)", $postID, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        $wpdb->query($post_view_sql);
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'increment_post_view_count');

This part doesn't work at all. I am unable to put data into my table, despite my INSERT INTO.
And third, retrieve the number of views by post
function post_views_count($post_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $view_count_sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS views FROM 'myprefix_posts_views' WHERE postid = %d", $post_id);
    $view_count = $wpdb->get_var($view_count_sql);
    return $view_count;
}

Any help will be appreciated.
Thx.

Are you recording every single hit/view of a post in a database table as a separate line item? And if you are, you need to add an index, check this out:  https://spinupwp.com/wordpress-database-optimization-indexing/

If you provided full code, issue is probably in this line:
$wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO 'myprefix_posts_views' (postid, ip, device) VALUES (%d, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE create_at=VALUES(create_at)", $postID, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

Because into column postid you are trying to put variable $postID, when you didn't declare it anywhere. This column is NOT NULL, so probably you have database error while adding new row.
You can add this to confirm:
$test = $wpdb->query($post_view_sql);
var_dump( $test );

Replacing $postId with $post->ID should fix the issue.

Thx for your help. var_dump($test) returns bool(false).

This mean that you have an error during adding new row into DB. If fix I proposed is not working for you, you can add:
$wpdb->show_errors();
$wpdb->print_error();
After the $wpdb->query()
This should show you the exact error with the query.
